# " ./bin/spark-shell " Not working with Pre-built version of Spark 1.6 with Hadoop 2.6+ on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-spark

Freshly downloaded the Pre-built version of Spark 1.6 with Hadoop 2.6+ on Ubuntu 14.04 onto the desktop.

I Navigated to the spark shell and initiated spark as per the link given below
[Quick Start Spark Link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#interactive-analysis-with-the-spark-shell) using

```
./bin/spark-shell
```

I am receiving the following errors . I saw a similar question asked for Mac OSX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601554/mac-spark-shell-error-initializing-sparkcontext) .

```
ashwin@Console:~/Desktop/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6$ ./bin/spark-shell
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_91)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/01/05 12:36:25 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$.createListenerAndUI(SQLContext.scala:1367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at <init>(<console>:26)
    at .<init>(<console>:30)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
                ^
```

Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried to run it with sudo? Maybe it requires root privileges.

Comment: @kometen Nope Sudo use is also not helping either. Same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523061/2777965

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar problem where my master fails to start with that exception when bringing up a cluster.

To fix this I altered a property I was setting in the $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh file.

Previously I had set the 'SPARK_MASTER_IP' to the ip address of my master node. Changing this to the public DNS of the box seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Thomas.  I am having the same issue and this did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause for your problem is that you are trying to bind to an illegal IP address. In the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`, there is variable named `$SPARK_LOCAL_IP`. If it is set, please make sure that it is really representing the machine, you are running the Spark shell on or try to comment it out. Otherwise, if it is not set, you can try to set it to, e.g., `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: the issue persists