# Why does Spark not run locally while it should be possible according the documentation?

Tags: apache-spark

The aim is to get started with Spark by executing some examples and investigate the output.

I have cloned the [Apache Spark repository](https://github.com/apache/spark), built it following the instructions in the Readme and ran `./bin/spark-shell` that results in:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/11/10 08:47:48 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 0)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:505)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:490)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:408)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/10 08:47:48 ERROR SparkContext: Error stopping SparkContext after init error.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1764)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2309)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:835)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:835)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:101)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 0)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:505)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:490)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
  at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:408)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

Running one of the examples fails as well:

```
scala> sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).count()
<console>:18: error: not found: value sc
       sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).count()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620983/bin-spark-shell-not-working-with-pre-built-version-of-spark-1-6-with-hadoo

Comment: What is the OS of your machine?

Comment: @yaron centos 7

Comment: And when you use a pre-build package from the spark website?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following two directions:

1) Help spark find your IP:

if your hostname isn't included in /etc/hosts add it to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1      your_hostname
```

set environment variable **SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"**

2) if exists - kill old spark process

Comment: Just a stupid question. Why do I need the double quotes? I tried without quotes and it didn't work.

Comment: Related to this, make sure you definitely have `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your /ect/hosts. Somehow mine was missing (?) and this caused the same issue as in the question. This answer prompted me to look

Answer (score 3):

You need to set environment variable `SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"`,

or run,

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1"
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, run command `hostname` on terminal, make sure this hostname exists in your `\etc\hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not for someone running on cluster machine of their own but on clouderaVM. While working on clouderaVM, I was getting the same error and the above solution didn't work.

Cause when i did

```
cat /etc/hosts/     
192.168.245.*** quickstart.cloudera
```

This id is different than my actual ip which my VM was running on. you can check that using ifconfig.

Solution is to shutdown the VM and restart it.