# Exception: ERROR SparkContext - Error initializing local SparkContext. java.net.BindException

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I'm trying to write a test for spark application, but I get this Exception when trying to run the next test

```
     class BasicIT {

      val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("basic.phase.it").setMaster("local[1]")
      var context:SparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    @Test
    def myTest(): Unit = {
      print("test")
     }
    }
```

fails with this exception:

```
2016-07-24 21:04:39,956 [main,95] ERROR SparkContext - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
```

currently working with IntelliJ on OS x Yosemite.

what am I doing wrong? the same code used to work ..

Answer (score 4):

Try using 
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1" to load-spark-env.sh or just set SPARK_LOCAL_IP="127.0.0.1" before running spark application. It worked for me.

Comment: yes this is the answer, I've added it in spark conf, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding *spark.driver.host* to be your localhost

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("AnyName").set("spark.driver.host", "localhost");
```

Comment: work for me. For sparkseesion :     val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("spark2")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.driver.host","localhost")
      .getOrCreate();

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some more logging telling you that the UI port specified by the config was already used. If this is the case, you need to set `spark.ui.port` explicitely to some value you know will be an available port on the master. When a particular port is not available, Spark tries to increment the port number.

**Example:**

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("basic.phase.it")
                               .setMaster("local[1]")
                               .set("spark.ui.port", "4080");
```

Comment: didn't work for me, is there another param I should set?

Comment: "didn't work" is not specific enough. What did you see in the logs ?

Comment: This is the fatal exception, but I'm sure you have more logging than this since it is retried 16 times

Comment: Please refer [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601554/mac-spark-shell-error-initializing-sparkcontext). This suggest many options to try for similar problem.