# Linux intellij idea spark Error initializing SparkContext

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I tried to run a spark 1.6.0 (spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6) program on local mode using intellij idea .It has the error below.(Chinese means you can not specify the address of the requested)

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/17 16:18:25 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/09/17 16:18:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/17 16:18:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ron
16/09/17 16:18:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ron
16/09/17 16:18:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(ron); users with modify permissions: Set(ron)
16/09/17 16:18:26 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/09/17 16:18:26 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: 无法指定被请求的地址: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/17 16:18:26 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: 无法指定被请求的地址: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries!
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Check this for some options. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601554/mac-spark-shell-error-initializing-sparkcontext

Comment: thank you very much . I have solved the problem.

Comment: If you have solved your problem try to put a self answer to your question. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

1.Get your hostname by using "hostname" command.

2.Make an entry in the /etc/hosts file for your hostname if not present as follows:

127.0.0.1      your_hostname